# <button type="submit"> compatibility?

Tags: html

I'd like to have a submit button that submits a different value than is displayed on the button. With `<input type="submit">` you can't seem to do this. With `<button type="submit">` however, these can be two different values. The question is, will it work in all browsers?

Trying this test code here:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="txt"/>
    <button type="submit" name="btn" value="val">text</button>
</form>
```

In FF 3.6 it updates my address bar with both values appropriately (and responds to me pressing enter in the text box). In IE 8, it also accepts pressing enter, displays the text value in the address bar, but it doesn't show the button's value as a GET param at all... does that mean it's not submitting it?

---

I can't use hidden inputs because I need to determine which button is clicked without JS.

---

Test 2:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="txt"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit1">submit</button>
    <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="submit2"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="submit3"/>
</form>
```

In IE8, hitting enter does not submit any of the buttons, but clicking submit1 *will* send a value. It'll send "submit", not "submit1" which is inconsistent with FF. However, submitting the form only sends the value of *one* button in both browsers, which means I might be able to check *which* button was clicked by checking if `GET['submitX']` exists instead!  Chrome has slightly different behavior on pressing enter (submits button2). Opera seems consistent with FF... but all 4 browsers only ever submit one button. I don't have any earlier versions of the browsers installed though.... does anyone know if it works in earlier versions, particularly IE6?

Comment: Don't you want to use `<input type="hidden" />` instead?

Comment: @vooD: No... the idea is that I want to have multiple submit buttons on the page, and I need them to do different things, without the usage of JavaScript.

Comment: to test in IE5 and IE6 and if you are running Windows, you can always use IE Tester @ http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oldish post but I think there is a solution that has been missed here. The `button[type=submit]` has always had problems with inconsistent behaviour, particularly with old IEs, and from @Mark's tests looks like we still have problems.

Instead you can use two different values for the `name` attribute of the `input[type=submit]` and parse these server-side to get the correct action. For example, you can do:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="txt"/>
    <input type="submit" name="action[do_something]" value="Do Something Cool"/>
    <input type="submit" name="action[do_another]" value="Do Something Dangerous"/>
</form>
```

Only the successful (clicked or default) name-value pair gets submitted so, say, in PHP you can easily do something like:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['action']['do_something'])) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do another thing
}
?>
```

Note the default action will always be the first that appears in the source.

Comment: I've taken this exact approach in the past; I guess I was looking for a cleaner/more semantic solution but at least this works reliably.

Comment: Do you happen to know for which IE does the button[type=submit] issue apply ?

Comment: @Zubzob Seems like it applies to IE8 in 'Quirks' mode. So if you are in IE8 and don't specify the doctype as (say) HTML5 you'll post the button text. Switch to standards mode and you'll post the `value` attribute.

Some quick testing with IE6 and IE7 + WinXP showed the button text being submitted whether or not a modern doctype was used.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an alternative if you aren't sure about using a button tag.

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="txt" />
    <input type="hidden" name="myinput" value="myvalue" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

This will be more consistent than a button tag as as some browsers actually submit the text inside of the button tags rather than its value attribute. For example

```
<button name="mybutton" type="submit" value="one">Two</button>
```

In some browsers, you would have "one" submitted, in others, "Two".

If you want to act conditionally depending on the particular button pressed, you would have to do so based on the text on the input...

In this example, the display text ("Button 1" or "Button 2") would be posted back.

Firefox: "?txt=&submit=Button+1"
IE: "?txt=&submit=Button+1"
Safari: "?txt=&submit=Button+1"

And so on. Giving two form elements the same name is generally accepted as being possible as browsers support it. It isn't formally documented though, so you'll have to decide if you want to act on it.

As a final alternative, is there any reason why you can't give them a form field that let's them choose the control flow rather than having two buttons?

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="txt" />
    <select name="myname">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want two buttons for the case you mention in your comment... i.e. one button half-way down the form to refresh something based on a sub-set of inputs and another button at the bottom to submit, this is how you should do things...

1) The buttons should both do the same thing - simply submit the form.

2) You should detect server-side if you have a valid form (if they are working sequentially and have hit the first of the two submits, you will have blank inputs for the second half of the form - rendering it invalid).

3) You should detect server-side if you have enough information to perform the calculation or refresh that you mention in your comment.

In cases 2 and 3, you should mark the fields that are required for the user to proceed.

This negates the need for particular buttons to do particular things - the user could type in the first half of the form and still hit the button at the bottom - so you don't want to base your logic on which button was pressed.

Comment: That blows. So much for standards.

Comment: I've added some extra info that may be of use - based on your note about wanting two buttons. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I want to *avoid* basing it on the displayed text. What if I want them both to have the same text? Or what if the text is dynamic or contains weird characters? I prefer not to mix display logic with code (testing against what should be a display-only value). Looking for a flexible solution... this is going into a framework. I don't want a select box either, it slows users down ;)

Comment: The problem is not the standards, but that you are attempting to impose a fault conditional effect that is not valid according to the standards.

Comment: Maybe conditional logic was never intended, but some consistent behavior across browsers would still be nice. My goal isn't even to have the two buttons do different things, I just need an extra button in the middle of my form to refresh the page based on some prior inputs, since JS is not always available to do so (i.e. make one select box populate a 2nd one). And in order to do that without JS, I need to submit the data... but I guess I can just check if the field I'm interested in is blank or not and make either button do what I want.

Comment: hidden fields are not a solution

Comment: @Ahwebdev please explain what you mean.

Comment: @SteveFenton Sorry, yes I explain, in a larger use case, when your are using loop for example on a post list,  and you want to submit only value of the related post. Using a unique form is not more possible with hidden fields because each field value will be sent. Using an input type button to send a unique value related to the action is the best way. Because it work inside and outside a loop.

Comment: If you only want to submit the row from the loop it would have its own form. If you want to present a list and get a selection there are form elements designed for that exact scenario (radio/checkbox). If you are stuck with this, ask a separate question rather than adapting a 3 year old one.

Answer (score 7):

This will do the trick on IE

```
<button type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit1" onclick="this.value='submit1' ">submit</button>
```

Simple and works on all browsers

Answer (score 1):

Use hidden fields, they are the best way to do it.

```
<input type="hidden" value="any value you want to enter" />
```

Comment: How does that give me 2 different vals depending on which button I clicked? I know I didn't make my intention explicit in the Q, but that's what I'm after.

Comment: add more buttons but change the names only

Comment: Now that sounds like it could be an actual solution. Not ideal, but workable.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for this problem. It works across browsers.

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="txt"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="btn" id="hiddenbtn" />
    <button type="submit" name="btn1" value="val">text</button>
</form>
```

Javascript (Requires jQuery):

```
$(document).ready( function{
    $(":submit[name='btn1']").on("click", function() {
        $("#hiddenbtn").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't attach values to buttons of type submit.  A button with type submit submits a form.  That is all it does and should ever hope to do.  Any submission method of any form is equal to all other submission methods of that same form in purpose and data scope.  To be logically correct to the intent of HTML you need to use separate forms if you wish different data to be conditionally returned upon submission.

I understand my answer is inconvenient but it is the only correct answer without adding and removing hidden input fields using JavaScript.

Comment: I disagree. You're arguing semantics, but there are times when rules of thumb need to be broken. HTML itself is semantically flawed; it was designed as a mix of semantic markup *and* display logic, so who cares about what was *intended*? This is the year 2010! I'm asking about what *works* and is *possible*, since we don't live in an ideal world :)

Comment: MML? I'm not making an email form here... if anything I'd use XML and XSLT.