# ModX and PDO: querying with PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, modx

I am new to PDO and have the follow code which recieves 2 PHP vars from a form and uses them in a query:

```
$loginemail = $_REQUEST['loginemail'] ;
$loginpassword = $_REQUEST['loginpassword'] ;

$logincheck = "SELECT * FROM `ft_gameusers` WHERE `email` = '$loginemail' AND `password` = '$loginpassword'";

$query = $modx->query($logincheck);

if ($query) {
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

 echo $row['email'];

    }
}
```

The thing is if I hard code the email and password variables into the MySQL query it works fine - its just doesnt seem to like them as PHP variables.

Does anyone know what Im doing wrong? (PS: this is a snippet within ModX Revo)

EDIT: form tag:

```
<form id="loginform" action="mysite.com/formprocess" method="post">

Email:
<input type="text" id="loginemail" name="loginemail">
Password:
<input type="password" id="loginpassword" name="loginpassword">
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: does your action in the form method refer to different page containing the code above or to itself where the above code resides?

Comment: @JLC007 a different page with the code above

Comment: Can you show us you <input> boxes plus submit button?

Comment: Check what loginemail and loginpassword contain by doing a var_dump() .. also - when you say hard code the variables do you mean the $_REQUEST[] variable or you actually put in real values for the email and password?

Comment: @JLC007 added above - but I do know the form is working as I can echo the results before the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can bind your parameters using PDO/xPDO:

```
$loginemail = $_REQUEST['loginemail'] ;
$loginpassword = $_REQUEST['loginpassword'] ;

$logincheck = "SELECT * FROM `ft_gameusers` WHERE `email` = :loginemail AND `password` = :loginpassword";

$credentials = array(
    ':loginemail' => $loginemail,
    ':loginpassword' => $loginpassword,
);

$query = new xPDOCriteria($modx,$logincheck,$credentials);
if ($query->stmt && $query->stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $query->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['email'];
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: I'm hoping this is a test case and you are not storing passwords in clear text in the database ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$logincheck = "SELECT * FROM `ft_gameusers` WHERE `email` = '".$loginemail."' AND `password` = '".$loginpassword.'";
```

Comment: what did you change? Variables inside double quotes are evaluated.

Comment: He asked that those username,passowrd are not gong to treat as php var,so i gave him a try..and it will also valid,and can check this

Comment: Im afraid that makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

Try changing FROM this

```
<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

TO

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583139/button-type-submit-compatibility) explains that `<button>` is not always compatible and might just explain why your variables that gets passed using `post` is empty on the other side.

[**FUTHER INFO**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) 
on the html5 `<button>` element

> Important: If you use the  element in an HTML form, different
>   browsers may submit different values. Internet Explorer, prior version
>   9, will submit the text between the  and  tags, while
>   other browsers will submit the content of the value attribute. Use the
>    element to create buttons in an HTML form.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` has both `$_POST` and `$_GET`

Comment: This doesnt make any difference either Im afraid

Answer (score 0):

I think Gautam's right here, ty a couple little tests to see what is actually going on:

```
// trim these just in case
$loginemail = trim($_REQUEST['loginemail']);
$loginpassword = trim($_REQUEST['loginpassword']);

$logincheck = "SELECT * FROM `ft_gameusers` 
WHERE `email` = '$loginemail' AND `password` = '$loginpassword'";

// copy & run this in an sql editor:
echo $logincheck;

// then try Gautam's ~ correct the quotes syntax error after loginpassword
$logincheck2 = "SELECT * FROM `ft_gameusers` 
WHERE `email` = '".$loginemail."' AND `password` = '".$loginpassword."';
echo $logincheck;
```

Comment: hmm still it does not work....its been suggested that ModX securities are blocking it. Does anyone know of a way to properly do the querie in PDO?