# Issue sending POST data from html button tag to PHP processing script

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, post

I'm having a rather irritating issue when trying to submit data from a html button tag via POST to a PHP processing script.

Here's my code...

(1) HTML form:

```
 <form id="pub-form1" method="post">
      <button type="submit" name="All" value="true">All Publishers</button>
      <button type="submit" name="Current" value="true">Current Publishers</button>
      <button type="submit" name="Users" value="true">User Priveleges</button>
 </form>
```

(2) jQuery script to handle POST request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#pub-form1').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#results').contents().remove();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $("input").prop("disabled", true);
    request = $.post('VRC_PublishersProcess.php', formData, resultsMessage);
    request.fail(function() { 
        $('#results').append("<span id=\"reply\">Your search failed for an unknown reason. Please try again in a few minutes.</ span>");            
        $("input").prop("disabled", false); });


    function resultsMessage(data) {
        $('#results').append(data);
        $("input").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

(3) PHP processing script:

```
    //All Publishers
if(isset($_POST['All'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['All'])) {
        $result = $members->selectAllMembers();
        if($result === true) {
            exit(); //Kill the process
        }
        else {
            echo $result;
            exit(); //Kill the process
        }
    }
    else {
        $error = "<span id=\"reply\">Not all fields were entered correctly!</ span>";
        echo $error;
        exit(); //Kill the process  
    }
}

//Current Publishers
if(isset($_POST['Current'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['Current'])) {
        $result = $members->selectCurrentPublishers();
        if($result === true) {
            exit(); //Kill the process
        }
        else {
            echo $result;
            exit(); //Kill the process
        }
    }
    else {
        $error = "<span id=\"reply\">Not all fields were entered correctly!</ span>";
        echo $error;
        exit(); //Kill the process  
    }
}

//Users
if(isset($_POST['Users'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['Users'])) {
        $result = $members->selectUserPublishers();
        if($result === true) {
            exit(); //Kill the process
        }
        else {
            echo $result;
            exit(); //Kill the process
        }
    }
    else {
        $error = "<span id=\"reply\">Not all fields were entered correctly!</ span>";
        echo $error;
        exit(); //Kill the process  
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what the cause of the issue is. No errors were thrown by javascript or PHP; the page remains blank with no results.

The jQuery function seems to be working correctly. I've use that particular several times on other forms and it handles the POST request properly. I was even able to trigger a failure on it; it responded correctly.

The PHP processing script also appears to be functioning properly. Again, it derived from other scripts that have successfully processed POST requests from the same page.

My suspicion is focused on the HTML form itself. These are my theories: (1) The button isn't submitting "itself." In other words, since there is no text or other forms of input, there's really nothing to submit. (2) For some reason the name is not corresponding to what my PHP script is looking for. For instance, if `"All Publishers"` was submitted, my PHP script is looking for `$_POST['All']`. But for some reason, that request isn't saved under that identifier in the PHP superglobal array.

My goal is to provide the end user with three options of displaying data. Right now, that isn't working.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Final Solution:

```
  <div id="pub1">
            <a href="#" class="drop" id="one">Other</a>
            <div id="displayselect" method="post">
                <form id="select1" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="All" value="1" />
                </form>
                <form id="select2" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Current" value="1" />
                </form>
                <form id="select3" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Users" value="1" />
                </form>
                <button type="submit" name="All" form="select1">All Publishers</button>
                <button type="submit" name="Current" form="select2">Current Publishers</button>
                <button type="submit" name="Users" form="select3">User Priveleges</button>
           </div>
        </div>
```

Obviously, appropriate modifications were made in the jQuery...

Comment: check this post I think you can find a answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583139/button-type-submit-compatibility

Comment: I glanced over that a little while ago. I am suspecting it is a similar issue, but I wanted to see if it happened to be anything else I am missing. Hidden fields may be the solution though - plus a few extra forms...

Comment: Try adding a `return false;` just right under `resultsMessage` closing bracket, I think the form is getting submitted.

Comment: try changing `<button type='submit'>` to `<input type='submit'>` in your form.

Comment: @Mlagma For debugging, use GET instead of POST, then you can see with your own eyes what gets submitted and under which name.

Comment: @OptimusPrime Why? What do you think that would solve?

Comment: @MrLister Some browsers interpret `<button type="...` in different ways. At least that's how some older editions behaved. For instance, sometimes instead of `name` being the identifier of the tag, the text in between the opening and closing tags would become the identifier.

Comment: @Guy I don't believe that is the issue. I used identical scripts for submitting my other forms, and they function properly. In fact, `e.preventDefault();` is disabling the form from submitting as it normally would. I ran into that issue before.

Comment: @Mlagma, give it a go mate :-), which jQuery version do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out,

jQuery.serialize didn't work out on the button (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) it only works on `input, textarea, select` so I tried switching your HTML `button` elements into `<input type="submit" ...` but that didn't work out as well because jQuery ignores the `submit` tags when serializing, I tried to add an `<input type="hidden" name="test" value="1" />` and checked out what it serialized was `test=1` so you'd have to change your form a bit.

jsFiddle for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/4D8Nz/