# OnClick working or not in enter key press?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a button in my page ,for which i need to track every hit on it

```
<button id="searchbutton" type="submit" 
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','search','Click','FClicks',1.00,true]);" 
name="Søg"></button>
```

Now what i want to know is weather this onclick script will work on enter press or not? I want to log every click on this button and I am not sure if user presses enter key deos this work or not?
Can any one help me out here?

Comment: If the button has focus it does. If it is <input type="submit" and there is only one field, it also does. I would for sure change it to <input type="submit" value="Søg" ... /> or put the code where it belongs in the form's submit event (assuming it is the only submit button)

Comment: Also read this about using the button tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583139/button-type-submit-compatibility

Comment: Apart from the tips here: you should learn how to debug. You could've answered your own question faster than posting it here by simply replacing the `_qac.push(...)` with a `console.log('Test!')` or something similar. Even better: you could've left the code in place and when you would've taken a look in the debugger tools of your browser in the network tab you should see a request sent to Google (or not if the code would'nt work). Either way: debugging would've been much faster than opening a question and waiting for an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the Javascript out of the `onclick` event, and place it to the form `onsubmit` to be sure. It would also help you if you generally place the code you need in a function and call that function in the form's `onsubmit`.