# HTML button/input I want to keep different text and value and read value in server

Tags: java, html, servlets, button, input

I tried googling this but didn't get a proper answer, so here goes the question to the experts on this forum:

I want to render a button on my web page such that it's value is different from what is displayed on screen. e.g if I use below html tag, Confirm is displayed.

```
<button name="type" value="save">Confirm</button>
```

However I want to read value "save" in the server so that I can have certain logic based on that. If I use

```
request.getParameter("type");
```

I get "Confirm" instead of "save".

My objective is to have multiple buttons with different values and at server side I want to know what button was clicked. I don't want to link the server code with the displayed text.

I can do a workaround such that `onsubmit` I call a javascript function that captures the button clicked and puts "save" in hidden field with name="type". But this seems like such a common client-server problem that there must be a more elegant solution to this problem that I am not aware of.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Is there something you've already tried, could you provide some code, so we can see that you put at least some effort to solve your problem by yourself?

Comment: Looks like my code snippet was missing in the final post. Edited and added my code snippet. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Can you post more of your code? Both the HTML form and the server side code? The behavior you are expecting IS in fact the expected behavior for the code you have shown. I suspect you have a bug elsewhere in your code (like maybe reusing the variable name somewhere).

Comment: I am using a custom framework where `request.getParameter` is replaced by `params.getString`. So posting my code as is will not help. Since you are saying that the behavior is expected, let me do a POC by stripping off the framework stuff. If it works as expected I will know that the framework is the culprit. Will update this post then.

Comment: Turns out the issue is not the framework I am using (as I was initially suspecting). It is the browser that decides what goes in the `POST` request. I will answer my own question for others reference.

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense that `<button>` works such that `value` attribute is sent in `POST` request whereas the displayed text is whatever is between `<button>...</button>`.

Unfortunately, standards don't define this behavior, so the browsers are left to implement it the way they want. In Firefox, `value` attribute is posted. But in Internet Explorer (I know about IE8, don't know if it changed in later version), `value` is not posted. Instead displayed text is posted!

In a nutshell you have to workaround this problem. There are a couple of good suggestions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2583139/4462410).

This is what I found most useful or worked for me the most. Add a hidden field with the same name as I intend to use in the server.

```
<input type="hidden" name="type" id="btntype" />
<button type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="save">Confirm</button>
<button type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="verify">Verify</button>
<button type="submit" name="submitbtn" vallue="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

And this in Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(":submit[name='submitbtn']").on("click", function() {
      $("#btntype").val($(this).val());
   });
});
```

Now, in the servlet, I can use:

```
request.getParameter("type");
```

It will give value `save` if Confirm is clicked, `verify` if Verify is clicked and `cancel` if Cancel button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This way also it will work. Just define the id for button.Whenever that particular submit button will be clicked just call .on() method

```
<button id="filter" value="value1" type="submit">Confirm</button>
<button id="filter" value="value2" type="submit">Verify</button>
<button id="filter" value="value3" type="submit">Cancel</button>

$(window).on("click", "#filter", function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
```