# php - How to make a unique $_POST to a form action?

Tags: php

I'm having a trouble finding a solution to this. Here is the case, assume that I have 5 books in the database, i will display them by doing a `while` then `mysql_fetch_array` assume that I create a table. This is the plot

```
echo"
<td>
<form action='bookext.php' method='post'>
<input type='submit' value='".$row['book_title']."'  style='border: 0; background: transparent';>WHAT TO PUT HERE</form></td>";
```

the `$row['book_title']` works fine because it must display what is the title of the book in the database. But, how can I get it's unique value which is `book_id` and send it to `bookext.php`? 
PS: Sorry for my title, I can't pull the right english

Comment: Create a hidden input with the book's id in it. Also, your input above needs a `name` attribute, like `name="title"`

Comment: What does the `name` attribute do?

Comment: When you submit the name attribute is the identifier in the `$_POST` array. For instance, `$_POST['title']` will have the value of the input with `name="title"`.

Comment: Can you please answer it with explanation? :)

Comment: More long strings of HTML echoed with PHP... Inline CSS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your current input needs a name attribute:

```
 "<input type='submit' name="title" value='".$row['book_title']."'  style='border: 0; background: transparent';>WHAT TO PUT HERE</form></td>";
```

Since you're using the POST method this will insure the value is available in the `$_POST` array, like `$_POST['title']`.

For the id you can add a hidden input to your form:

```
"<input type='hidden' name='book_id' value='".$row['book_id']."'>"
```

This will be available to you in `$_POST['book_id']` when you submit.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't `echo` the book title in the posted page :(

Comment: If you echo `$_POST['book_title']` in the posted page it will work.

Comment: Once I figure out knowing how to determine which geodesy/projection is currently being utilized it'll be even more beautiful! @Fred-ii-

Comment: You'll figure it out.

Comment: I'm sure that I will. In the mean time I am learning *a lot*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just insert hidden field to your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="POST_NAME" value="YOUR_VALUE_TO_IDENTIFY">
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use forms in tables.

```
<form action='bookext.php' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
<?php foreach($books AS $book){ ?> 
<td>
  <button type="submit" name="bookId" value="<?php echo $book['id']; ?>">
    Title of the book
  </button>
</td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

bookext.php

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['bookId'];
```

Comment: Imo using `buttons` for this is actually beter then dealing with `hidden` inputs

Comment: If you ask w3schools, you shouldn't; "different browsers may submit different values". But it always works for me.

Comment: w3fools... How should they submit the value differnt?

Comment: This explains the problem with buttons, base your choise on your target group, will they use really old browsers or not? [StackOverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2583175/4637793)

Comment: Its a post from 4 years ago. If it works for IE8 i'm sastisfied :)

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `<button>` doesn't work as expected in IE7. IE7 was included in the early builds of W7 (2009), a lot of the people without interest of technology still uses IE7. But these people probably go to the store to buy their books, so @WTFZane could probably use `<button>` in this case, without any problems.