# Adding +1 onto a MySQL value via button

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to enable a counter system, which adds +1 to a specific value in the MySQL table. However when a user presses the +1, it times 1 by the number of rows available, and adds that value to the original instead. For example, I have 5 rows in the table, 5 x 1 is 5. This is added onto the existing total.

The code is here:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Request</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
            <th>Options</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, name, request, rating, report FROM requests WHERE visible     = 1 ORDER BY rating DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

if($_POST[rate]){ //they have clicked the submit button
                $error = ''; //truncate the errors
                if($error){ //errors have occurred
                    echo 'Sorry. The following error(s) occurred:<br>        <br>'.$error.'<br>&laquo; <a href="home.php">Back</a>';
                }else{ //no errors
                                    $id = $_POST['rate'];
                    mysql_query("UPDATE requests SET rating = rating + 1 WHERE id = $id");
                }
            }else{ //not clicked the submit button
                echo '

<form method="post" class="form-inline">

<tr><td>' . $row["id"]. '</td><td>' . $row["name"]. '</td><td>' . $row["request"]. '</td><td>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="rate" value="' . $row["id"] . '">+ ' . $row["rating"] . '</button></td><td>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="" value="">Like (0)</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="" value="">Comment (0)    </button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="" value="">Report</button></td></tr>
                </form>

';
            }


}
} else {
echo "There is currently no outstanding requests!";
}
$conn->close();
?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Are you sure the control is going to the part where they press the submit button ? I think `if($_POST[rate]){` should be `if($_POST['rate']){`.

Comment: Also, I think `if($_POST['rate'])` should be `if (isset($_POST['rate']))`

Comment: That hasn't worked unfortunately, same outcome. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you are trying to mix and match `mysql_` and `mysqli_` APIs. `mysql_query("UPDATE requests` should be `mysqli_query("UPDATE requests`. Try making this change in addition to other things that I recommended. Also, make sure that you have PHP error reporting turned on for your code.

Comment: Hello Max, thank you for noticing this, I have made this change, although once more it hasn't made a difference. The code does work, it's just the numerical value which is incorrect. But once more, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Shouldn't `$id` value be coming from the db query? So shouldn't it be `$id = $row['id'];` ?

Comment: Possibly, however it does add the value to the correct row ID, so how could that be the issue?

Comment: If it's working for you now and you are getting the result that you wanted, then I would say that was the problem.

Comment: This is not the case. It's working, but the original problem still occurs. Please read the original post.

Comment: Shouldn't button type=submit be input type=submit ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583139/button-type-submit-compatibility

Comment: I think it's a good idea if you separate out the form updating and form generating parts.

Comment: You should also probable take out the update query from the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Define the previous rating then +1 to it;

**Example**

You will need to add this before the update & edit the $result['rating']; to whatever code echoes out the current rating

```
$updatetrating = $result['rating'] +1;
```

then in your update query change +1 to $currentrating and it should update the row by adding 1.

**Example**

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `requests` SET `rating` = '$updaterating' WHERE `id` = '$id'");
            }
```

Comment: I am unsure how to specify what the current rating is, to be able to add the 1.