# Form is not submitting data on mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I  have a form with a submit button, the form works fine on PC view. however when on mobile view the button is not functional and the form won't submit. Note that I'm using bootstrap and jQuery frameworks.

Here's the code:

```html
<form method="post" action="purchase/buy/<?php echo $info[0]->sno;?>" data-ajax="false">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg " id="buttons">buy now</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you please try `<input type="submit" value="buy now">`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583139/button-type-submit-compatibility

Comment: Tried that, still not working :(

Comment: it must be js problem not html

Comment: I have so many forms on the website, this is the only one with the problem it's quite weird

Comment: Hey @AmmarAli, I tested this html and it works just fine on mobile. Is this code live somewhere? This is definitely being affected by js or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the problem, it was a div containing my form that was causing the problem, I removed it and everything works fine now.